# Why I lose my session variable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, session-variables

I´m on MVC and using KnockoputJS. I select the value from 2 select. In the first select i choose IDCompany,  and the second select i choose IDSubsidiary.

I send the model in Json to JsonResult in the controller and I create a variable session and a cookie and save IDCompany in the Session variable and in the cookie with the same name.

I do the same with IDSubsidiary. Finally, I return to the ajax function (which call "Save" at first)

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Save(ViewModel viewModel)
{
  Session["IDCompany"] = viewModel.IDCompany.ToString();
  Response.Cookies["IDCompany"].Value = viewModel.IDCompany.ToString();
  Response.Cookies["IDCompany"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

  Session["IDSubsidiary"] = viewModel.IDSubsidiary.ToString();
  Response.Cookies["IDSubsidiary"].Value = viewModel.IDSubsidiary.ToString();
  Response.Cookies["IDSubsidiary"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

  return Json(true);
}
```

The problem is that after a while (30 mins approximately), i lose `Session["IDCompany"]` and `Session["IDSubsidiary"]` (becomes null).
The problem can be that, for example, Session["IDSubsidiary"] and `Response.Cookies["IDSubsidiary"]` has the same name?

Comment: Sessions do expire after a certain period of time.  If you want to persist this data permanently, perhaps a database is a better place to store it?

Comment: The session has a timeout and is simply killed after a certain amount of time... and 30 minutes may be that value, you'll have to check server configuration for that.

Comment: The session can be lost at any time for reasons outside of your control. You need to be able to detect this situation and rebuild/recover. I suggest abstracting all session object access behind a facade layer that can detect the nulls and reset itself so that it's not noticed by the calling code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two reasons this could be happening. 1) The session is timing out, or 2) you are using "In Process" session state.

If the user sits on a page for thirty minutes, and then the value is gone the next time they refresh or go to another page, its likely a timeout problem. You could try increasing the sessionState timeout; however, you'll probably start running into the issue described below. If you are determined to use Session variables, you should probably switch to a different state mode than "in process" which is the default.

If it is not timing out, the reason your value is lost is because "In Process" session state, goes away when the App Pool recycles. This can happen for a variety of reasons. You probably want to change your session state mode to State Server or SQL Server. This will keep your session data around between app pool recycles, but you will need to enable the "ASP.NET Session State Service" on the web server if you go the State Server route.

There are several state modes, each with different behaviors. You can read about them [here on MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx)

Comment: This note on the msdn page is critical if you do use this route: `Objects stored in session state must be serializable if the mode is set to StateServer`

Comment: It seems more likely that this is a session timeout, since he says it happens after 30 minutes.

Comment: @JohnSaunders That's a fair point; I was assuming it was going away even with user activity (which should reset the timeout count down). I'll update to include that too.

Comment: The default timeout, if not set in web.config is 20 minutes. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks
Look for indications of that happening.